# Change to setposition by class for JS

Tags: javascript

Here is a code: http://jsfiddle.net/QQaZp/1/

```
 var setPosition = function() {
    $('div').css('top', ($(window).height()-50));
}

$(window).ready(function(){
    setPosition();
}).resize(function(){
    setPosition();
});
```

I would like to add a class to the div. Ex:

> div class="name"

and then use that class in the JS that is in the fiddle.

What would be the new code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add class using jquery [addclass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method.

```js
 var setPosition = function() {
    $('.name').css('top', ($(window).height()-50));
}

$(window).ready(function(){
  $("div").addClass("name");
    setPosition();
}).resize(function(){
    setPosition();
});
```

```css
div { position: absolute; width: 400px; background-color: purple; height: 400px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div>oh hey there</div>
```

Comment: @Aloha glad to help

Comment: For some reason it works well in localhost but doesn't on the server. Weird enough, on the server if I change the .name to div the code works (obvisouly not like it is intended... but I can see it work). I can also see that the addClasse ("name") worked on both tries, So.. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Not sure why, but I needed to switch two scripts for it to work on the server.

Comment: @Aloha so you want to put your class name as `div` ??

Comment: for some reason the script didn't work on the server but when I switched place with another script, they both worked.  So, its all good now.  Thanks @Mahi